# How to color columns in a Html table with spanning tds

Tags: html, css

I want to keep column background colors even if there are some spanning `td`elements in the table. This image illustrates what I want to achieve.[image] The columns should be completely colored, regardless of the `td` elements.

The code that I´ve got currently looks like this: http://www.bootply.com/9rjGrpg37X

As you can see, the `td` which spans 4 columns is also colored orange but instead I want to color it also green and blue like on the image above.

Is this even possible with html/css?

Comment: Sure. Make a css class with a background-color: color value; and apply it to your HTML.

Comment: @AllDani they provided a bootply

Comment: @AndrewBone I'm on mobile though..

Comment: hi flash did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the use of `linear-gradient` like this :

html :

```
    <tr>
        <td class="try" colspan="3">
            <div class="centered green">333</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

css :

```
    .try{
        background :linear-gradient(90deg, #FF9950 43.34%, #92D050 43.34%, #92D050 71.66%, #9ED3D7 71.66%);
    }
```

But it's not responsive ;(

You must try to find the % of the width of your column

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps you.

**css**

```
.table td, .table th{width:33.334% !important;}
.col3{position:relative; width:calc(300% + 8px*4);}
```

**html**

```
<td>
   <div class="centered green col3">333</div>
</td>
```

http://www.bootply.com/dG4mHK0WW9

Comment: Is there a solution which still works with the colspan?